# Calling Methods in a User Control from another page dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

I´m writing a page that need to call an User Control Method dynamically.

1. I have a GridView on my page and on the RowDataBound I´m loading this User Control for each row.
2. At my User Control I have a public void Method that I need to call when I load this Control.

I was reading about reflection, but at the code that I used, the method that I created on the User Control wasn´t found. See the code:

`UserControl x = (UserControl)LoadControl("../usercontrols/ucResultData.ascx");
x.GetType().InvokeMember("CreateData", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Page, null);`

This is the code on the User Control:

`public void CriarGradeHorario()
    {
...
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke the method `CreateData` on the current Page object. You want to invoke the `CriarGradeHorario` method on the user control object:

```
x.GetType()
  .InvokeMember("CriarGradeHorario", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, x, null);
```

However, if you want to call the method this way, you should consider moving it out of the user control and put it in a class file. That way you can call it without using reflection.